# Email dataframes without and with Styling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, html-email

I am running some tests to send emails from my python script with 2 dataframes: one is raw (ie without styling) and the other one is with styling. For styles I followed the example (output 9) from the [pandas-style documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

I copy/pasted the definition of the styling function below:

```
def highlight_max(s):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series yellow.
    '''
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in is_max]

def color_negative_red(val):
    """
    Takes a scalar and returns a string with
    the css property `'color: red'` for negative
    strings, black otherwise.
    """
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

I created a dummy dataframe to run my tests as

```
np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
           axis=1)
df.iloc[3, 3] = np.nan
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan
```

And here is the standard send_email function:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib

def send_email():
    df1 = df.copy()
    styler = df1.style.applymap(color_negative_red).apply(highlight_max).hide_index()

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = "This is a test"
    msg['From'] = 'abc@dfe.com'
    msg['To'] = 'abc@dfe.com'

    html = """
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <p>Hello!<br>
                <br>
                Raw:<br>
                {0}
                <br>
                Formated<br>
               {1}
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    """.format(df.to_html(), styler.render())

    part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(the_user, the_password)
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```

I would expect the formated dataframe to show without index, with max row values highlighted in yellow and negative numbers to be in red.

Here is a screenshot of the email that I sent/received:

[image]

So the formated dataframe has indeed no index but the max highlight in yellow and the red negative number formating are missing. Am I missing something in the styler variable? for instance, do I need to use the .set_table_styles()? if so, how?

EDIT: here is the output of styler.render() at least the top part of it

```
<style  type="text/css" >
#T_181a6_row0_col0,#T_181a6_row0_col1,(...){
            color:  black;
       }

#T_181a6_row0_col3,#T_181a6_row0_col4,(...){
            color:  red;
       }
#T_181a6_row2_col4,#T_181a6_row6_col2,(...){
            color:  black;
            background-color:  yellow;
       }
</style><table id="T_181a6_" ><thead>    
<tr>
<th class="col_heading level0 col0" >A</th>        
<th class="col_heading level0 col1" >B</th>        
<th class="col_heading level0 col2" >C</th>        
<th class="col_heading level0 col3" >D</th>        
<th class="col_heading level0 col4" >E</th>    
</tr></thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td id="T_181a6_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1.000000</td>
    <td id="T_181a6_row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >1.329212</td>
    <td id="T_181a6_row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >nan</td>
    <td id="T_181a6_row0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >-0.316280</td>
    <td id="T_181a6_row0_col4" class="data row0 col4" >-0.990810</td>
</tr>
(...)
</tbody></table>
```

Edit2: sorry about the formating of the html code not sure how I can do this...

Edit3: when I save down the output of styler.render() as html and open that file in google for instance the dataframe is correctly formated. So now I am wondering if the problem lies with how I include styler.render() into the html body (?) I notice that then I have < body >...< / body > included inside another < body >...< / body > is that correct?

Edit 4: output of the html variable saved down as html and opened in chrome:
[image]

So the issue is that webmail are stripping out the styles heading, which should be within each td of the html. Is there a way to do that within the render() function?

Comment: I don't know python but I do know email, and perhaps the problem is with the final html, so would you mind posting the output HTML?

Comment: @Nathan, I edited my original post to include part of the html output. From the heading it does look like some cells are supposed to be in red and some others with yellow background.

Comment: Some email clients simply strip out `<head>` and `<style>` tags entirely. See e.g. https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Comment: @tripleee: I used your link and it seems that render is omitting some "style" in each < td > row, for instance the following is not part of the render() output:  style="color: black;background-color: yellow;"

Comment: You've got the styles in the `<style>...</style>` section, is it possible to write them into the `<td>` directly? As per triplee's comment, many desktop environments, and webmails, strip the `<style>` tags. Can you test on a mobile and see if it's working?

Comment: I saved down the entire html variable (ie the email body with the raw dataframe and the formated dataframe) into a .html file and opened it up in my browser: the two dataframes are being shown exactly as intended (I will add a screenshot as Edit4 in my original post. The problem now is since this should be readable from webmail, I need to add the style directly onto the corresponding < td > lines: how can I do that automatically (not having to go add the style one by one)? isn't there an option to do that within the python render() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with would look like this:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib
from premailer import transform

def send_email():
    styler = (df_details.style.apply(highlight_same_week, axis=None).hide_index()).render()

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = "This is a test"
    msg['From'] = 'abc@dfe.com'
    msg['To'] = 'abc@dfe.com'

    html = """
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <p>Hello!<br>
                <br>
                Raw:<br>
                {0}
                <br>
                Formated<br>
               {1}
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    """.format(df.to_html(), styler)

    html = transform(html)
    part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(the_user, the_password)
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```

and highlight_same_week looks like this:

```
    def highlight_same_week(s):
        return pd.DataFrame(df_template.values, columns=s.columns)
```

So df_details is the dataframe with the values I am interested to style while df_template is a dataframe with the same dimensions as df_details but its values are styling elements, for instance:

```
df_template.iloc[x, y] = 'background-color: #ffff00'
```

So the main points to fix/correct were:

- using the right functions to create the styler variable (first line in the send_email function)
- using a dataframe template with the desired styles (here I am only highlithing in yellow the row where two column values are within the same week, based on datetime.isocalendar())
- tranform my raw HTML variable with the transform function from the premailer library

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks @Nathan and @tripleee for pointing out at the core issue. I have installed the library premailer which allows to transform the html document and move the styles from the < style > ... < / style > section to the relevant part of the html code. I now can receive the correctly formated datfarame onto my email.

Comment: Hi @Hotone, How did you achieve this? can you post your solution here?

Comment: Hi @Mulagala, I don't have the original code I used but the idea I apply is the following: I created a duplicate dataframe where I stored the various styles for each cells (eg. df_template.iloc[x, y] = 'background-color: #ffff00', then I used:
styler = (df_details.style.apply(self.highlight_same_week, axis=None).hide_index()).render() Finally, I inserted the styler object into my html code in the def send_email() function and used transform from the premailer library as follow:
html = transform(html)

I will write a proper answer as I fear this might not be clear enough